# Передать массив в xajax

Tags: ajax, php, json

Библиотека [xajax](http://www.xajax-project.org/) 0.6 beta 1.

В этой версии xajax, массивы из JS в PHP передаются как JSON, а раньше передавались как просто обычный или ассоциативный PHP массив, с которым сразу можно работать. Как вернуть эту возможность?

К тому же, при использовании `json_decode($data)`, и проверки `json_last_error()`, выдает `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`.

Сам JSON объект выглядит так:

```
{\"account_name\":\"Testname \",
    \"account_email\":\"test@yandex.ru\",
    \"account_group\":\"7\",
    \"accountId\":\"1\"}`
```

Comment: интересно, как это *из JS в PHP раньше передавались как просто обычный или ассоциативный PHP массив* а покажите как вы обрабатываете этот ответ...

Answer (score 1):

[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto), я могу предположить, что в старых версиях библиотеки (*сам с ней никогда не работал и не собираюсь*), данные обрабатывались самой библиотекой и вполне возможно, что на выходе могли представлять собой ассоциативный массив. Но как бы там ни было, я не могу понять, почему ТС не может обработать json-строку?

```
$json = "{\"account_name\":\"Testname \",
    \"account_email\":\"test@yandex.ru\",
    \"account_group\":\"7\",
    \"accountId\":\"1\"}";

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

Выдало результат:

```
Array
(
    [account_name] => Testname 
    [account_email] => test@yandex.ru
    [account_group] => 7
    [accountId] => 1
)
```

Comment: Проблема была в magic_quotes_gpc, из за них json нельзя было превратить в массив.